# How secured is a 24 character password?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I use a 24 character password for my accounts. But how secured are they really? The characters are made of A-Z in Capital letters, a-z in small caps, 0-9, and special characters consisting "!@#$%^&*()"

So how many tries will it take to brute force it? Considering **each character can only repeat no more than thrice** in any single password so that no password ends up looking like kkkkkkkkkkk1111111112222.

I'd really like to know the answers.

Comment: When you say each character can only repeat thrice, do you mean that there cannot be a substring of identical characters more than three in length, or do you mean a character cannot appear more than thrice in total in the password?

Comment: I mean the character cannot appear more than thrice in total within the password

Comment: Well for a start you can get a lower bound for how many possible passwords there are. We have 26+26+10+10=72 characters and 24 spaces to fill, so if all characters are distinct there are [$72!/(72-24)!\approx 4.93\times 10^{42}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=72%21%2F%2872-24%29%21) possible passwords. Allowing for repetition complicates things by allowing for more passwords;  you would have to add in the number of passwords having duplicates or triplicates.

Comment: @SarcasticSaturdayClub does these answers help you , if so ,you can upvote and accept

Answer (score 1):

This question is very suitable for *[EXPONENTIAL GENERATING FUNCTIONS](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section03.02.html)* to show its power. When i look at your questions ,we see that there is not any restriction about character types , so each character is seem individual and independent. Moreover , it is said that each character can repeat at most thrice. Then , the exponential generating function of each character is equal to $$\bigg(1+ \frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\bigg)$$

Whats more , we have $72$ characters in total. Then , find the coefficient of $\frac{x^{24}}{24!}$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(1+ \frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\bigg)^{72}$$ , or find the coefficent of $x^{24}$ in the expansion ,and multiply it by $24!$ , namely $$24! \times [x^{24}]\bigg(1+ \frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\bigg)^{72}$$

I give you *[LINK](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coefficient+of+x%5E24+in+%281%2Bx+%2Bx%5E2+%2F2+%2B+x%5E3+%2F6%29%5E72)* containing the calculation of the expansion.

As you see , the result is $$24! \times \frac{55,367,603,210,998,525,936,076,341}{93,312}= 3.681492296817581e+44$$

Answer (score 0):

I am going to attempt to answer a more general question. Suppose there are $N$ distinct characters to choose from and we wish to form a password $L$ characters long. Your setup has $$L=24,\\N=26+26+10+10=72.$$

The question is how many possible passwords are there if no character appears more than thrice in total.

---

First, let's suppose we decide that $m$ different characters will be used once, $n$ different characters will be duplicated, and $p$ different characters will be triplicated. Then the following constraints must be obeyed:

$$m+n+p\leq N \quad (1)\\
m+2n+3p=L.\quad (2)$$

Note that constraint $(1)$ is automatically satisfied by constraint $(2)$ if $L\leq N$ (which happens in your case).

Having decided $m,n,p,$ we must actually choose among the $N$ characters which ones will appear once, which will be duplicated, which will be triplicated, and which will not be used.  There are

$${N \choose m,n,p,N-m-n-p}=\frac{N!}{m!n!p!(N-m-n-p)!}$$

ways to choose these character assignments.

Next, among the $L$ slots in our password to fill, $m$ slots must be chosen for the characters appearing once, $n$ slot pairs must be chosen for all the duplicates, and $p$ slot triples must be chosen for all the triplicates. So there are

$${L\choose \underbrace{1,...,1}_{m},\underbrace{2,...,2}_{n},\underbrace{3,...,3}_{p}}=\frac{L!}{1!^m2!^n3!^p}$$

ways to assign the chosen characters to slots.

Putting this all together, the total number of passwords is given by the following:

$$\sum_{(m,n,p)\in A}\frac{N!}{m!n!p!(N-m-n-p)!}\frac{L!}{1!^m2!^n3!^p},\\
A\equiv \left \{(m,n,p)\in \mathbb{Z}_+^3\bigg| m+n+p\leq N,m+2n+3p=L\right\}.$$